# I've added the Admob SDK to my app, and the ads are showing. If I want to integrate Mopub with Admob, will I have to add additional code?

Tags: android, admob, mopub

How does integrating one network into another work? I created an acccount on mopub, and made an ad unit. I didn't integrate the Mopub SDK into my app, instead I just copied the Mopub ad unit ID, and added Mopub as a mediation on Admob, with that ad unit ID. Did I go about it the right way? Because on Mopub's dashboard it shows 0 impressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have done is correct, but you still need to include the Mopub library in your app because the Admob mediator will invoke the Mopub classes when Mopub has been selected in the mediation flow.

Comment: Thanks. So all I need to do is add the library to gradle? No additional code?

Comment: The mopub wiki says `We strongly recommend compiling your app against the Google Play Services Library in order to use the Android Advertising ID instead of the device ID, as required by Google.`.. I can't make much sense of it. What is it they are asking to do?

Comment: They are just saying to use the Admob library (which is part of Google Play Services). Admob makes use of the Android advertising Id for tracking purposes instead of device ID.